# Удаление списка файлов

Tags: c#, ftp

Как разумно удалить большой список файлов на FTP?

Можно удалять через `FtpWebRequest`, но, как я понимаю, удаление большого списка будет весьма длительным, т.к. для каждого файла необходимо составлять новый запрос и заново коннектиться. Или же это не так?

Comment: По идее, есть [`FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Заново коннектиться не обязательно

```
using (var connection = new FTPConnection()) //Тут создаем новое соединение
{
     foreach (string file in files)
         //Тут удаляем файл
} //Тут ваше соединение закрывается автоматически вызовом IDisposable
```